# How does the function const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {} works and what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, function, mern

While reading through the docs of MUI , I encountered with a new syntax of the arrow function in js and I didn't see it anywhere. I tried to understand  it's working and I can't find it anywhere.

The syntax is followed by

```
  const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
  };
```

and it passes to the onChange event like this

```
      <EmailText
        label="Email"
        type={"email"}
        onChange={handleChange("email")}
      />
```

How does this function work and what is the meaning of this function and how did the onChange pass the event parameter to the function?

Answer (score 0):

`handleChange` function returns new function. which means when you call it - you will get a function expression and NOT a function call, this is way you can call it in the `onClick` without wrapping it in another arrow function